# Syntax for Assign Macro with Argument (buttons)

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, arguments

I create a pretty button-style object in Excel.
I right-click, Assign Macro.
The syntax, which used to work, to invoke the macro with an argument was:

```
'SubName "Argument"'
```

And my sub had a matching name and expected a String variable type as its only argument.

My specific example looks like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UnhideTab(ByVal SheetName As String)
'MsgBox "Running UnhideTab " & SheetName

Dim Sheet As Worksheet
'Dim newshtname As String

For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    If Sheet.Name = SheetName Then
        If Sheet.Visible = True Then
            Sheet.Copy After:=Sheet
            Sheets("Client Info").Select
'            MsgBox "What is this instance of " & SheetName & "called?", vbOKCancel, "Name New Sheet"
        Else:
            Sheet.Visible = True
        End If
    End If
Next Sheet
End Sub
```

For the button, I then put in the Assign Macro box for example:

```
'UnhideTab "Challenger"'
```

And it would unhide the Challenger tab. Worked for over a year perfectly well.
Now, since the last few days, it doesn't work anymore.

Error Message is as if it's not getting an Argument at all:

"Sorry, we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

Anyone know why?

[EDIT] If I replace the syntax in the Assign Macro box with exactly what was there before, it works...! As I say, they all used to work fine... Nothing changed...

[EDIT] results shown here:

Image of working vs not working code. I believe when I pasted and overwrote the 'not working' code, it added reference to the workbook at the start, wrapped in single quotes ''. Still no idea why it broke / resolved.

[image: Erroring code to left, working code to right]

Comment: I'd suspect your comment about an MS update is correct but who can say. This isn't officially documented syntax so always a bit risky to use - and, if I recall correctly, it won't work at all in an xlsb format workbook.

Comment: True, xlsb probably fails but it's all internal anyway and we don't use xlsb... Someday I'll update it to call a function that knows the name of the button that was clicked... But for now, it's working again :)

Answer (score -1):

You cannot run procedures with arguments directly, you need to write another procedure which will call the `UnhideTab` like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub UnhideTab(ByVal SheetName As String)
'MsgBox "Running UnhideTab " & SheetName

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName)
'Dim newshtname As String
    With ws
        If .Visible = True Then
            .Copy After:=ws
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Client Info").Select
    '            MsgBox "What is this instance of " & SheetName & "called?", vbOKCancel, "Name New Sheet"
        Else
            .Visible = True
        End If
    End With

End Sub
Sub Unhide()

    UnhideTab "MySheet"

End Sub
```

I also changed your code, you don't need to loop through each worksheet, you know which worksheet you want to check so only use it's name.

Comment: Thanks Damian, true I don't need to loop through all worksheets. However, I can run macros with arguments directly: https://exceloffthegrid.com/assign-macro-with-arguments-to-a-form-control-button/ see half way down, "Running a macro with arguments"

Comment: @jfgoodhew1 If it helped, please consider marking the answer as correct so others might find it easily.

Comment: Well, it helped but you didn't answer why the previously operational syntax stopped working, whereas if I reinput the exact same syntax (using copy and paste) into the Assign Macro box for my button.. It works again. I'm assuming Microsoft Update shenanigans but.. who knows..

Comment: My mistake, can you show a print of your working code and the one which doesn't? a print image